# Where should I ask a question about tools, services, or methods for testing which PHP code is more efficient

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Where is the best place in the stack network to ask questions about or recommendations for 3rd party resources, tools, etc...? The question I'd like to ask is:

> I'm looking for a way to understand/test my .PHP code to see which method of doing something is more efficient and/or requires fewer server resources.
>
> Does anyone know of a website, system, or method for testing different versions of code to see which requires the least amount of server resources and/or time?

Comment: @Ano do you know which site is best for this question? Every time I ask for 3rd party solutions or tools I'm told "I'm can't ask that".

Comment: I've edited your question to a strict site recommendation. You can not just ask your question here because you don't know where you **should** ask it. Have you looked at the help center on [softwarerecs.se]?

Comment: @Catija, I haven't but I will. Will I get 'dinged' for asking the question in two different places?

Comment: Normally, yes. We don't really allow cross posting of identical question on two sites... but you're not asking the question here... you're just asking where to ask it.

Comment: @Catija I don't think this question will fly on software recommendations.

Comment: Shot, I just posted the question there. https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/48679/what-tools-services-or-methods-are-there-for-testing-which-php-script-is-more

Comment: Did you read their help center page about how to ask? https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 3):

As was pointed out in the comments, Software Recommendations is the place to ask for tool recommendations.

**However!!!**
The site has very strict quality guidelines. They have to prevent spammers from filling up the site, or people just suggesting their favorite tool. So, you must have very specific requirements in your question.
Their guidelines are [here](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/35246) and are also linked from their Help Center.

There is one other aspect to your question here. If you aren't interested in tools, but in a constructive criticism of your code - then [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) is the place to go. That is where you can post your code and ask others to look at it.
The difference between Code Review and Stack Overflow is that Code Review is for code that already works, but that you want to improve.